# problems after update with libdrm

Tags: 12.04, software-sources

I've got problem with updating. Sorry for polish language in log, but it is default language in my system. I'm using ubuntu 12.04 gnome remix.

Anybody know how to fix it?

> `Należy uruchomić "apt-get -f install", aby naprawić poniższe problemy: Następujące pakiety mają niespełnione zależności: libdrm-dev : Wymaga: > (= 2.4.40+git20121123.171666e4-0ubuntu0ricotz2~precise) ale >2.4.32-1ubuntu1 ma zostać zainstalowany libdrm-intel1 : Wymaga: libdrm2 (>= 2.4.38) ale 2.4.32-1ubuntu1 ma zostać zainstalowany libdrm-nouveau2 : Wymaga: libdrm2 (>= 2.4.38) ale 2.4.32-1ubuntu1 ma zostać zainstalowany libdrm-radeon1 : Wymaga: libdrm2 (>= 2.4.38) ale 2.4.32-1ubuntu1 ma zostać zainstalowany libdrm2 : Narusza zależności: libdrm2:i386 (!= 2.4.32-1ubuntu1) ale >2.4.40+git20121123.171666e4-0ubuntu0ricotz2~precise ma zostać zainstalowany libdrm2:i386 : Narusza zależności: libdrm2 (!= 2.4.40+git20121123.171666e4->0ubuntu0ricotz2~precise) ale 2.4.32-1ubuntu1 ma zostać zainstalowany`
>
> `You should run "apt-get-f install" to fix the following problems: The following packages have unmet dependencies: libdrm-dev: Depends:> (= 4.2.40 + git20121123.171666e4-0ubuntu0ricotz2 ~ precise) but> 2.4.32-1ubuntu1 is to be installed libdrm-intel1: Requires: libdrm2 (> = 2.4.38) but 2.4.32-1ubuntu1 is to be installed libdrm-nouveau2: Requires: libdrm2 (> = 2.4.38) but 2.4.32-1ubuntu1 is to be installed libdrm -radeon1: Requires: libdrm2 (> = 2.4.38) but 2.4.32-1ubuntu1 is to be installed libdrm2: depending violates: libdrm2: i386 (! = 2.4.32-1ubuntu1) but> 4.2.40 + git20121123.171666e4-0ubuntu0ricotz2 ~ precise to be installed libdrm2: i386: depending violates: libdrm2 (! = 2.4.40 + git20121123.171666e4-> 0ubuntu0ricotz2 ~ precise) but 2.4.32-1ubuntu1 is to be installed`

Comment: checked it before posting. Don't work.

Comment: you can try also `sudo apt-get -r install libdrm-dev` ... OR
restart to Recovery kernel and run 'dpkg' ...

Comment: you mean sudo apt-get -f install libdrm-dev ?? Not -r? Checked too.  I checked other kernel too but it still don't work

Comment: no, not `--fix` but `--reinstall` option

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install` - to common system fix, `sudo apt-get -r install libdrm-dev` - to reinstall package, but most credible is it also reinstall signed packages from `ricotz ppa`

Comment: dont work too ;/

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

[image: Image by WebUpd8]
<sub>*Image by Alin Andrey, WebUpd8*</sub>

It is problem with your xorg-edgers packages ...

[xorg-edgers precise ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa)

Thus. I have not idea why your packages was downgraded, or some package that tried to be updated have dependencies to updated package. Possible way it is:

> Check your Software Sources.
>
> If it needed install **ppa-purge**:
>    `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`
>
> Refer to this link for how-to-use **ppa-purge**:
>    [Install PPA-Purge With Multi-Arch Support In
>    Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-ppa-purge-with-multi-arch.html)
>
> Thus, first need to fix your Software Sources that to provide automatic updates.

Comment: But I can not install anything ;/

Comment: then refer this: [Package Manager Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure) ... and please post your output.